# Bash - Extracting Data from XML

Tags: xml, bash

**See XML example below.**

Using a bash script, how could I extract the Strings between all the "from" tags in the XML file into say, an array?
i.e. Something like array=[Ben, Jani, James, Harry, ...]

**Example XML file:**

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Ben</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>James</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to solve this?

Comment: You should add a root element. Like <notes> for example.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: @jil has informed me that my initial solution only works if the XML file is formatted as OP pasted, but fails if there are multiple `<from>` tags per line.  The following code fixes that issue, as it removes all new line characters first:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAMES=()
one_line=$(sed "s/\n//g" file.xml)
from_names=$(echo $one_line | grep -Po "<from>(.*?)<\/from>")

for word in $from_names
do
    name=$(echo $word | sed -n "s/<from>\(.*\)<\/from>/\1/p")
    NAMES+=($name)
done

echo ${NAMES[@]}
```

Then you can reference each name like `${NAMES[0]}`, `${NAMES[1]}`, `${NAMES[2]}`, etc.

`echo ${NAMES[@]}` at the end of the script prints out all elements of the list and is great for testing.

Comment: Will break if there is more than one XML tag per input line.

Comment: @jil Edited my code to resolve that problem.  Should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

this is not an xml aware command, expects the tags are on each separate lines.

```
$ arr=$(sed -rn 's_<from>(.*)</from>_\1_p' xml)
$ echo ${arr[@]}
Ben Jani James
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use some XML shell tool such as *xmlstarlet* or *xmllint* or *xpath* (from XML::XPath Perl module).

E.g. using *xpath*:

```
array=( $(xpath -q -e "//from/text()" input_file.xml) )
```

using *xmllint* and *sed*:

```
array=( $(xmllint --xpath '//from' input_file.xml \
          | sed 's#</\?from># #g') )
```

P.S. Your sample input is not well-formed (it is missing the root-element)